# Loops, "have n items to process but only n-1 update steps"

Tags: loops, language-agnostic

Consider the following loop:

```
marker_stream = 0
for character in input_file:
            if character != ',':
               marker_stream |= 1
            marker_stream <<= 1
```

For each character in `input_file_contents`, this loop does a processing step, stores the result of the processing step (either a `0` or `1` bit) in `marker_stream`, and then shifts `marker_stream` over by one position to prepare for the next iteration.

Here's the problem: I want to process each character in the input file, but I only want to shift `marker_stream` `number of characters in the input file - 1` times. The loop above shifts `marker_stream` one too many times.

Now, I know I could add `marker_stream >>= 1` after the for loop, or I could maintain some flag that says whether or not the character we're currently processing is the last character in the file, but neither of these solutions seem that great. The flag solution involves flags (yuck), and the extra line solution could be confusing if the processing loop was longer.

I'm looking for a more elegant solution to this problem, and, more generally the "I have n items to process but have an update step I want to run only n-1 times" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Process the first element in the file separately; treat the file as a one-entry head with a tail holding the rest of the entries:

```
// Process head
entry <- readNext(inFile)
write(entry, outFile)

// Process tail
while (NOT inFile.endOfFile)
  write(separator, outFile)
  entry <- readNext(inFile)
  write(entry, outFile)
endwhile
```

The head entry does not follow a separator; the tail entries all follow a separator.  You get your 'n-1' effect by treating the single head entry differently from the n-1 tail entries in the file.